# Notepad++, regex: replace any hyphen (-) occurring after a non-blank character with a colon (:)

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

The question is in the title.

Thanks.

Comment: Hah ... Great explanations *"the question is in the title"* ..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about replacing `(\S)-` with `\1:` ?

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Notepad++ supports positive lookbehinds. In which case replace `(?<=\S)-` with `:` using the find/replace tool.

(Updated to use `\S` to match any non-whitespace character instead of `[^ ]` to match a non-space specifically, as was suggested in the comments.)

Comment: Positive lookbehind is very elegant, you don't need to repeat the other character. It might be more accurate at the begging of the line.
On the other hand, `\S` is more accurate than `[^ ]`

Comment: @TamasRev, you're right; `\S` is definitely better. I've updated my answer accordingly.